# ESLint no-multi-spaces allow within object declaration

Tags: javascript, eslint

How do I configure the [no-multi-spaces](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-multi-spaces.html) rule to allow the following:

```
var arr = [
    {id: 'abc',    content: 'foo'},
    {id: 'cdefgh', content: 'bar'}
];
```

By default it complains about the space before `content`. I guess I need to add an AST node to the `exceptions` but I don't know which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In the documentation it is stated](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-multi-spaces.html#options):

> The easiest way to determine the node types for exceptions is to use the [online demo](http://eslint.org/parser/).

So I went ahead and put your code in there and got the AST. The following part seems to be the relevant one:

```
{
  "type": "ObjectExpression",
  "start": 16,
  "end": 46,
  "properties": [
    {
      "type": "Property",
      "start": 17,
      "end": 26,
      "key": {
        "type": "Identifier",
        "start": 17,
        "end": 19,
        "name": "id"
      },
      "value": {
        "type": "Literal",
        "start": 21,
        "end": 26,
        "value": "abc",
        "raw": "'abc'"
      },
      "kind": "init"
    },
    {
      "type": "Property",
      "start": 31,
      "end": 45,
      "key": {
        "type": "Identifier",
        "start": 31,
        "end": 38,
        "name": "content"
      },
      "value": {
        "type": "Literal",
        "start": 40,
        "end": 45,
        "value": "foo",
        "raw": "'foo'"
      },
      "kind": "init"
    }
  ]
},
```

Since your code seems to pertain to the whole object, I would guess that the AST node you seek is `ObjectExpression`.

```
/* eslint no-multi-spaces: [2, { exceptions: { "ObjectExpression": true } }] */
```

Please let me know if this works.